# Calling C++ struct parameter from C#

Tags: c#, c++

Below is the header documentation to call the DLL:

```
#define CM24_NUMTYPENOTE            24

typedef struct SNOTETYPE
{
    char     Notetype[6];
    int      NumNote;
} SNOTE;

typedef struct SDEP
{
    int      InNumber;
    int      TotalDepBnk;
    int      Refused;
    int      Unrecognized;
    SNOTE    Types[CM24_NUMTYPENOTE*4];
} SDEPOSIT;

typedef SDEPOSIT *PADEPOSITCASS;

int APIENTRY InterDoCheck                   (int , PADEPOSITCASS);
```

And here is my code in C# which is calling the C++ DLL

```
public struct SNOTE
{
    public String notetype;
    public int numNote;
}

public struct SDEPOSIT
{
    public int InNumber;
    public int TotalDepBnk;
    public int Refused;
    public int Unrecognized;
    public SNOTE[] Types;
}

[DllImport("myDLL.dll")]
public static extern int InterDoCheck(int mode, ref SDEPOSIT PADEPOSITCASS);

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SDEPOSIT sdeposit = new SDEPOSIT();
    deposit.Types = new SNOTE[96];
    int r = InterDoCheck(0, ref sdeposit);
}
```

So, here when I click the button it will call the DLL and getting an error below:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   WindowsFormsApp2.exe The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

I tried to commented out the line `SDEPOSIT sdeposit = new SDEPOSIT();` It was calling successfully but it's  getting hang when receiving the result from DLL.

I'm not sure if I'm I calling it correctly, or is my struct in C# is correct or not.
Basically I want to know how to pass values to this type of struct in C++.

Comment: Hi Merkithuseyin, thanks for replying, I can call other function to this DLL that has simple  parameter. But this function InterDoCheck has a complex parameters and want to know how to pass the values.

Comment: A string in c# is not the same as a string in c++.  A c# string is a class which in c++ a string is one byte array terminated with '\0'.  So you add [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] above the string.  SNOTES you have to allocate the size so put above the array ; [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2, SizeConst =  24)]   I suspect the SNOTE in c++ is 4 because an int is 2 bytes in the c++.  SNOTE is size 4 in c++ because it has 6 bytes [6/2 = 3] and one integer which is 3 + 1 = 4.

Comment: Hi jdweng, thank you for your time answering my query. I tried your suggestion and I ended up with below code.

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public String notetype;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 24)]
public SNOTE[] Types;

i'm getting error using U2 so I followed the intelisense suggestion to use ByValArray

and before calling the function I instantiate the SNOTE with below size of array

SDEPOSIT sdeposit = new SDEPOSIT();
sdeposit.Types = new SNOTE[24];

InterDoDeposit(0, ref sdeposit); 

With this updated code I receiving a crash during the return.

Comment: I think all the int should be u16.  Making larger may cause mis-alignments but  not cause an exception. You need of allocate the size of sdeposit as unmanaged memory using Marshal.  Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(sdeposit));  The structure is passed on the stack and is not valid after returning from the method.   The stack values are reused by the parent method.

Comment: Again thank you for another suggestion, still no luck after allocating the size of sdeposit. I will continue to figure out this tomorrow. 

one question before I go to sleep. According to documentation it says 

SNOTE Types[24 *4];  isn't total of 96?

Comment: Yes!! I knew that. Changing from UnmanagedType.U2 to UnmanagedType.U4 would solve that.